# Applying a hamming window before FFT

Tags: ios, signal-processing

I am currently detecting frequencies using FFT. I am aware that I need to apply a window before doing the FFT but I am unsure how to do this.

What exactly should be done to apply a window.

I malloc is using

```
float * hammingWindow = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * numberOfFrames);
vDSP_hamm_window(hammingWindow, n, 0);
```

but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

When I call vmul with my args

`vDSP_vmul((COMPLEX*)outputBuffer, 1, hammingWindow, 1, (COMPLEX*)outputBuffer, 1, n);`

I get an error that vDSP_vmul does not exist even though I am calling other vDSP methods.

I call this after my FFT function

```
vDSP_zvmags((COMPLEX *)outputBuffer, 1, (COMPLEX *)outputBuffer, 1, bufferCapacity);
```

and I get the same issue - `No matching function for call to vDSP_zvmags`

What am I doing wrong? Are my arguments incorrect. It looks like `(COMPLEX *)outputBuffer` should not be passed in for two of the args.

Comment: You don't *need* to apply a window for this to work, it just works better with the window. Try without it first.

Comment: I don't know the iOS functions you are dealing with but this sounds like a linker issue, not an issue with windowing or pitch detection. That said, I have a tutorial on pitch detection, maybe it will help: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: @BjornRoche - Thanks for the help. What exactly does this main function output? I currently use Core-Audio render callback and I write to a file asynchronously just before running the fft. Am I right that this code will replace all the audio code that I currently use to access the mic data?

Comment: Don't completely understand your question, but my code reads from the mike and prints the estimated pitch to the console. IDK if PortAudio (which is used for reading from the mike) will work on iOS, but most of the code is pretty platform agnostic.